# Delete a row in google spreadsheet base on contents of cell in row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have this script to delete certain rows, if the selected cell in the selected colum has the metioned content but i don't understand where it fails

```
    function DeleteRowByKeyword() {

  var value_to_check = Browser.inputBox("Enter the keyword to trigger delete Row","", Browser.Buttons.OK);

  //  prendo quello attivo
  var DATA_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var FIRST_COLUMN = Browser.inputBox("Number of Column to look at (eg: for column A enter 1)","", Browser.Buttons.OK);

  ss.toast("removing duplicates...","",-1);

  var dataCopy1 = DATA_SHEET.getDataRange().getValues();
  var deleted_rows = 0;
  var rangeToCopy = '';

  if (dataCopy1.length > 0) {
    var i = 1;

    while (i < DATA_SHEET.getMaxRows() - deleted_rows) {
  if ((dataCopy1[i][FIRST_COLUMN]).search(value_to_check) != -1) {

    ss.deleteRow(i);
    deleted_rows++;
  } 
  i++;
    }
  }


  ss.toast("Done! " + deleted_rows + ' rows removed',"",5);
    }
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things to be improved:

- Remember that spreadsheet rows and columns are numbered starting at
  1, for all methods in the SpreadsheetApp, while javascript arrays
  start numbering from 0. You need to adjust between those numeric
  bases when working with both.
- The `String.search()` method may be an inappropriate choice here, for
  two reasons. The `.search()` will match substrings, so
  `('Testing').search('i')` finds a match; you may want to look for exact
  matches instead. Also, `.search()` includes support for regex
  matching, so users may be surprised to find their input interpreted
  as regex; `.indexOf()` may be a better choice.
- To limit operations to rows that contain data, use `.getLastRow()`
  instead of `.getMaxRows()`.
- When deleting rows, the size of the spreadsheet `dataRange` will get
  smaller; you did take that into account, but because you're looping
  up to the maximum size, the code is complicated by this requirement.
  You can simplify things by looping down from the maximum.
- The input of a Column Number is error-prone, so let the user enter a
  letter; you can convert it to a number.
- You had not defined a value for `ss` (within this function).

Here's the updated code:

```
function DeleteRowByKeyword() {

  var value_to_check = Browser.inputBox("Enter the keyword to trigger delete Row", "", Browser.Buttons.OK);

  var matchCol = Browser.inputBox("Column Letter to look at", "", Browser.Buttons.OK);
  var FIRST_COLUMN = (matchCol.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1);  // Convert, e.g. "A" -> 1

  //  prendo quello attivo (get active sheet)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DATA_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  ss.toast("removing duplicates...", "", -1);

  var dataCopy1 = DATA_SHEET.getDataRange().getValues();
  var deleted_rows = 0;

  if (dataCopy1.length > 0) {
    var i = DATA_SHEET.getLastRow();  // start at bottom

    while (i > 0) {
      if (dataCopy1[i-1][FIRST_COLUMN-1] === value_to_check) {

        ss.deleteRow(i);
        deleted_rows++;
      }
      i--;
    }
  }

  ss.toast("Done! " + deleted_rows + ' rows removed', "", 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using .search since i need a broad match (i have a large email database to cleanup from free emails). The loop now works great and also the column letter is much better than before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the index for deletion is the correct index. When you delete a row all bellow rows has their indexes changed -1. 
So try this code:

```
if (dataCopy1.length > 0) {
var i = 1;

while (i < DATA_SHEET.getMaxRows() - deleted_rows) {
 if ((dataCopy1[i][FIRST_COLUMN]).search(value_to_check) != -1) {

   ss.deleteRow(i - deleted_rows);
  deleted_rows++;
 } 
i++;
}
}
```